# Convert an NSURL to an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsurl

I have an app where the user can choose an image either from the built-in app images or from the iphone photo library. I use an object Occasion that has an `NSString` property to save the `imagePath`.

Now in the case of the built-in app images I do get the file name as an `NSString` an save in the `[occasion imagePath]`. But in the 2nd case where the user picks an image form the photo library I get an `NSURL` which I want to convert to an `NSString` to be able to save it in `[occasion imagePath`].

Is it possible to convert the `NSURL` to an `NSString`?

Answer (score 706, accepted):

In Objective-C:

```
NSString *myString = myURL.absoluteString;
```

In Swift:

```
var myString = myURL.absoluteString
```

More info in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1409868-absolutestring?language=objc):

Answer (score 136):

If you're interested in the pure string:

```
[myUrl absoluteString];
```

If you're interested in the path represented by the URL (and to be used with `NSFileManager` methods for example):

```
[myUrl path];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanx for your answer. As I'm trying to load the image from the straing I saved, I'm really interested in what you mentioned about using NSFileManager with `[myUril path];` When I used path instead of absoluteString it gave me the name `asset.jpg` Could you pleas eelaborate more how to use this to load the image into a UIImage instance?

Comment: Hi. Of course from the file name to get a real file system path you need to know where the file is stored and then create the full path (directory + filename) by composing them using NSString's stringByAppendingPathComponent: .The only exception to this rule is when you know the image is stored in the app bundle, in this case you can just use the [UIImage imageNamed:"name"] call which does the full job for you. But in the other cases you have to specify your full path.

Comment: Hi, thanx again for your answer. I'm still confused on how to load the image to a UIImage using this NSString `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000001&ext=JPG` which I saved by converting the result of `[myUrl absoluteString]` after converting it to an NSString. Here I made this question on this regard but got no answer. I'd appreciate it if you can answer it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085267/load-an-image-to-uiimage-from-a-file-path-to-the-asset-library/8086096#8086096]

Comment: yes, we should use myUrl.path instead of myUrl.absoluteString when you want to use it with NSFileManager, thanks Viggo24!!

Comment: Since you have an `assets-library` URL, rather than a `file` one, it's incompatible with `NSFileManager`. Access to such URLs is controlled strictly by `ALAssetsLibrary`.

Comment: This is the more accurate answer, since it displays the different string representations of the NSURL. There are times, like working with NSFileManager, where the absoluteString is not helpful.

Comment: What happens if NSURL is nil. Don't you get _fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_

Comment: In Objective-C there are no Optional values. All messages sent to nil return 0.

Answer (score 47):

Try this in Swift :

```
var urlString = myUrl.absoluteString
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString *urlString = [myURL absoluteString];
```

Comment: I used NSString *urlString = [myURL absoluteString];
But I had met this error and xcode was crashed.

-[__NSCFString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x791a18e0

Comment: @VõMaiTrinh that means your `myURL` is an object of NSString class. As NSString doesn't have `absoluteString` method then it leads to a crash.

Answer (score 17):

Swift update:

```
var myUrlStr : String = myUrl.absoluteString
```

Comment: You could omit `String` since Swift uses type inference.

Comment: You actually *should* omit `String` - the Swift Design Guidelines try to achieve as little redundant code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just fought with this very thing and this update didn't work.

This eventually did in Swift:

```
let myUrlStr : String = myUrl!.relativePath!
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use any one way**

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url1];
```

or

```
NSString *str=[url1 absoluteString];

NSLog(@"string :: %@",string);
```

> string :: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2D7570B-D5A6-45A0-8EAAA1F7476071FE/RemoDuplicateMedia.app/loading_circle_animation.gif

```
NSLog(@"str :: %@", str);
```

> str :: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2D7570B-D5A6-45A0-8EAA-A1F7476071FE/RemoDuplicateMedia.app/loading_circle_animation.gif

Answer (score -1):

In Swift :- 
var str_url = yourUrl.absoluteString

It will result a url in string.

Comment: Duplicate of [answer provided 4 years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24249988/1549818)