# How to use imageWithContentsOfFile when images are stored in Assets Catalog library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Due to memory management issues I am using `imageWithContentsOfFile` instead of `imageNamed`, but I'm having issues accessing the images stored in `Images.xcassets` folder.

I have values stored in an `NSDictionary` that corresponds to the image name within the `Asset library`, i.e. image1, image2, etc.

```
viewDidLoad:

{
    images = @{@"01"    : @"image1",
               @"02"    : @"image2",
               @"03"    : @"image3"
               //more keys and values };

    numbers = [ [contestants allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // code to set up the cell

    NSString *number = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *nameByNumber = [images objectForKey:number];

    NSString *name = [nameByNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"] ];

    return cell;
}
```

However, the cell is empty, no image. I even tried to hard-code the `NSString pathForResource`, but nothing?

How can I achieve this using `Asset Catalog`?

Thanks

Comment: Dumb question but just to be explicit: were you to use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"name"]` then the image would appear? So `+[UIImage imageNamed]` can find the thing but seemingly `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` cannot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load an image to UIImage from a file path to the asset library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085267/load-an-image-to-uiimage-from-a-file-path-to-the-asset-library)

Comment: @Tommy, yes that is correct. using `[UIImage imageNamed:name]` finds the appropriate image name within the Asset Catalog but using `-[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` does not, in fact `cell.imageView.image` returns `null`

Comment: @girish there's confusion here about the term Asset Library, the question you refer to is talking about ALAssetLibrary (images in the users device photo album)  This question is asking about an image in an Asset Catalog.

Comment: Tell me more about this memory management issue and why you think how you load the image matters.

Comment: I think this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856283/use-xcassets-without-imagenamed-to-prevent-memory-problems/23438145#23438145