# Objective-c how to convert NSURL into NSString?

Tags: objective-c, string

Total objective-c noob here with a question.
Is there a way to convert NSURL into NSString in one line?
I need to retrieve URL from sqlite database abd then save it into string.

Currently the line i want to convert looks like this ->

```
MyString.url = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
```

so ofcourse im getting 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSURL *' from 'NSString *''

:)

Comment: Looks like this MyString.url is of type NSURL..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an NSURL to an NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082719/convert-an-nsurl-to-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This :

```
NSString *aStrUrl = [aUrlObj absoluteString];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `absoluteString` property of `NSURL`

Example:

```
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
```

In Swift

```
var urlString = url.absoluteString
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on swift than use :

```
var urlStr : String = myUrl.absoluteString
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use any one**

```
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url1];


or 

NSString *str=[url1 absoluteString];

NSLog(@"string :: %@",string);
```

> string :: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2D7570B-D5A6-45A0-8EAAA1F7476071FE/DuplicateMedia.app/loading_circle_animation.gif

```
    NSLog(@"str :: %@", str);
```

> str :: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E2D7570B-D5A6-45A0-8EAA-A1F7476071FE/DuplicateMedia.app/loading_circle_animation.gif