# How can i check that is there any existing file is there from nsfilemanager?

Tags: ios, swift

// here frit i want to save a mp4 file before saving i want to check is it alreday there.if there than create another name

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let  savePathUrl = NSURL(string: ("\(documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp"))" + ".mp4"))
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: **savePathUrl**)// here i get error
    }

{
    do

    {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: **savePathUrl**)// here i get error
    }
    catch { }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an NSURL to an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082719/convert-an-nsurl-to-an-nsstring)

Comment: i just edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the way you create `savePathUrl` makes little sense. Replace:

```
let  savePathUrl = NSURL(string: ("\(documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp"))" + ".mp4"))
```

with:

```
let savePathUrl = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")
```

And then for the two `FileManager` manager methods you need a file path. To get a file path from a file URL, you need to use the `path` property.

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: savePathUrl.path) {
```